# How to get public key in .cer or .crt formats

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have created self-signed SSL certificate using OpenSSL as follow:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

This gave me certificate and private key in `.pem` file. I need to provide my public key to my clients in `.cer` or `.crt` format. **Is there any way to get public key in `.cer`/`.crt` formats?**

What I have already tried:

**1. Generating public key in `.pem` format and trying to convert it to `.cer` or `.crt` [*Didn't work*]**

To extract public key in `.pem` file [worked fine]:

```
`openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in signer-cert.pem  > signer-public-key-test.pem`
```

To convert it from `.pem` for `.cer` format
`openssl x509 -inform PEM -in signer-public-key-test.pem -outform DER -out signer-public-key-test.cer`
I get this error:

```
unable to load certificate
140067363030680:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

**2. Converting my certificate to .cer (which I did fine) and trying to export public key using windows certificate export wizard as instructions given [here](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1295563-step-4-export-public-key---fda-esg)**

It didn't work either. I couldn't enable the option to export keys and the final output, when opened in notepad++ was garbage.

So my question is, is there any way to generate the certificate from scratch and have the public key in `.cer` or `.crt` file. OR generating the certificate in `.pem` format and later extracting public keys to `.crt` or `.cer`

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Filenames extensions are just for human, they do not mean anything just by themselves. `.cer` looks like an ill-fated attempt to shoehorn a more meaningful `.cert` into old 8.3 convention, which should not be needed nowadays anyway. What is important is the content of it.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek You are right. file extensions don't matter. But when I say that I want my public key in `cer`/`cert` format  I mean that the public key should be encoded in _binary encoding methods for data described by ASN.1_

Comment: .crt and .cer are *certificate* formats. Certificates contain public keys, and it is almost certain that what you really want to supply is the certificate, not just the public key. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since `.cer` and `.crt` usually mean "DER or PEM-DER X.509 certificate" I don't know what you mean by having the public key in that format.

If you mean you want a DER encoded SubjectPublicKeyInfo representing the public key, the second stage of your pipeline would be

```
openssl asn1parse -noout -out some.file
```

You can remove the intermediate with

```
openssl x509 -in signer-cert.pem -noout -pubkey | 
    openssl asn1parse -noout -out signer-public-key-test.der
```

(Newline added to remove scrollbar)

Or, skip the certificate middleman altogether:

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout -outform der -out signer-public-key-test.der
```

Seems pretty weird that you want that particular format, though.

Comment: Can you explain your 1st and second command and SubjectPublicKeyInfo? I tried to convert to der using your last  command and I get this error: `unable to load Private Key
139899830797976:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I say in cer or crt format I mean  _binary encoding methods for data described by ASN.1_. If you go to this [link](https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem). It says "Within the RSA, PKCS#1 and SSL/TLS communities the Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER) encoding of ASN.1 is used to represent keys, certificates and such in a portable format.". Can you clarify a bit why are you finding it weird?

Comment: The `asn1parse` subcommand reads PEM (or you can use `-inform DER`), and if you give it `-out file` it will write to that file in DER.  SubjectPublicKeyInfo is the data format for public keys in a certificate, which is what `-pubkey` emitted.  It's weird because usually people want a whole certificate, a PEM SubjectPublicKeyInfo ("BEGIN PUBLIC KEY") or a PEM/DER RSAPublicKey.  Wanting a DER SubjectPublicKeyInfo isn't anything I can really say I've come across.